# Is there a way to source only a specified portion of SPSS syntax from another SPSS syntax file?

Tags: syntax, macros, spss

Is there a way to source only a specified portion of SPSS syntax from another SPSS syntax file?  I know about insert but was wondering if there was some code to specify running certain sections of a syntax file, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

you could divide your "other" syntax into relevant portions, and turn each portion into a macro. For example:

```
define Syn_Por_1 ()
compute a=1.
compute b=2.
!enddefine.

define Syn_Por_2 ()
compute c=mean(a,b).
compute d=c/2.
!enddefine.
```

Now you can `insert` the whole syntax, but that would not actually do anything but define the macros. After that you'll be able to run portions of the syntax by calling the relevant macros. For example:

```
.....
Syn_Por_1.
.....
Syn_Por_2.
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eli said, there is no way to have INSERT only run a portion of a file, but the macro or just breaking it into modular pieces would work.  For more elaborate subsetting, some Python code along with some markup convention in the file(s) could do the job.